# Python: Connect with Lotus Domino via COM

Tags: python-3.x, lotus-domino, win32com

I am trying to develop a REST Api in Python 3.6 that will facilitate data passing between 
a Lotus Domino database and a remote web server.

Unfortunately I can't get python to connect with Domino.

The conventional approach is to use win32com to gain access to Domino's COM interface.

My python code to achieve this is:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
session = Dispatch('Lotus.Notessession')
session.Initialize(password)
db = session.getDatabase(serverName, fileName)
```

Unfortunately, the code fails at line 2, with the warning: 'Error writing to 
process file pid.nbf, (other applications may be inappropriately accessing this file)'

Others have come up against this problem, and for some the solution was to ensure the user has write access to the Notes Data directory (& hence pid.nbf).  I have tried this, to no avail.

IBM states [(see Accessing the Domino Objects through COM)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_ACCESSING_THE_DOMINO_OBJECTS_THROUGH_COM.html) that the COM interface is available on a computer containing any of the following:

- Domino® Designer Release 5.0.2b or later
- Domino Server Release 5.0.2b or later
- Notes® Client Release 5.0.2b or later

The Domino or Notes software must be installed but need not be running.

The Domino COM objects must be able to locate a valid notes.ini file, looking first in the Domino or Notes program directory and then at the PATH system variable.

My 64 bit server has Domino Server Release 8.5 installed (no Notes Client is installed on the server).  My python code also runs on the Domino server (I have installed the 32 bit version of python however, in order to ensure compatability with win32com). As my software runs on the server, the relevant notes.ini file is the server's, located at E:\Lotus\Domino. I have tried running the python code with the Domino software both running and not.  Both result in the above error.

I'm running out of steam on this one.  Can anyone point me in the right direction.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This won't work: Domino 64 bit does not contain 32bit DLLs...

Comment: IBM only supports the COM classes on Win32. They can be made to work on Win64, but you have to register them, and some of the methods (mostly the ones that deal with collections of design elements) are known to fail.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what version of Domino you are running, but recent versions have a built-in REST API called Domino Access Services. https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp%3FlookupName=IBM+Domino+Access+Services+9.0.1

Comment: Thank you both for your responses.  We are running Domino version 8.5.1.  Looks like an upgrade to 8.5.3 (or later) is on the cards.

Comment: Why would you "upgrade" to a five to eight year old version. Move to 9.0.1 Feature Pack 9 instead as there are TONS of benefits

Comment: @Newbs Some sites may not be entitled to upgrade to 9.0.1.